# getting two values of an array of object displaying one versus the other on vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

im working in a vue js exercise , being on that point where in i have an array of objects and i want to display 2 players with diferents names , as final result on whichever html display result,: here my array of objects:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "player": {
            "id": 1,
            "player": "Jack Bauer",
            "email": "j.bauer@ctu.gov2",
            "password": "24"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "player": {
            "id": 2,
            "player": "Chloe O'Brian",
            "email": "c.obrian@ctu.gov",
            "password": "42"
        }
    }
]
```

and this is my template on vuejs in order to show lets say Chloe O'Brian versus Jack Bauer

```
<div v-for='(players,i) in getGamePlayerId' :key='players' >
   the player is {{getGamePlayerId.game.players_in_game}}</div> 
</div>
```

Is there a way using a double loop to compare both names and expose both different name

Comment: the path in the template(getGamePlayerId.game.players_in_game) is just what finally is exposed in the array of Objects

Comment: If you have >2 players in the array of objects, how do you know who is playing against who?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, in my opinion the best way is to first work on the array a little.

Maybe grouping the players 2by2 and then loop that array instead. To do this you can use [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    players: [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "player": {
          "id": 1,
          "player": "Jack Bauer",
          "email": "j.bauer@ctu.gov2",
          "password": "24"
         }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "player": {
          "id": 2,
          "player": "Chloe O'Brian",
          "email": "c.obrian@ctu.gov",
          "password": "42"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  
  computed: {
    matches () {
      return this.players.reduce((matches, item, index, arr) => {
        if (index !== arr.length - 1) {
          matches.push({player: item, opponent: arr[index + 1]})
        }
      
        return matches
      }, []);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <h3>Matches</h3>
  <div v-for="(match, index) in matches" :key="index">
    <div>
      {{ match.player.player.player }} <strong>vs</strong> {{ match.opponent.player.player }}       </div>        
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
```